# AppWarp RoomID in Unity SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, appwarp

I'm creating app in Unity and faced with problem in room id.

I create an "AppWarp Realtime Multiplayer Backend" app in App42 Cloud API but i do not see Roomid varible but it is in Unity.

What i'm doing wrong?

[APP WARP OUTPUT IMAGE](https://pp.vk.me/c621829/v621829143/2bd2b/jFTOA2k7uCQ.jpg)

[UNITY EDITOR OUTPUT](https://pp.vk.me/c621829/v621829143/2bd42/1DNQ4D8UKbE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connect to AppWrap API using your API key and Secret key (I don't think you should show us those keys in your picture you better remove them) your should create a room or a lobby yourself to interact with other players in it.
consider reading [Standard User Guide](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/unity3d-game-developers-home/unity3d-usage-guide/) that AppWarp provided there are also some useful tutorials available on that page.
also there is a C# Reference API avaliable [here](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/csharp-api-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created the dynamic room using the APIs. 
In AppHQ (App42 Cloud API) dashboard, you can only see the static rooms. Dynamic rooms which have been created using AppWarp APIs will not be visible in AppHQ dashboard.

Comment: oooy maybe you can save my day...
How to create dynamic room?